# Login in Ubuntu 22.04.1 goes back to login challenge

Tags: login

When I try to login in my Ubuntu 22.04.1 I succeed in login but The next screen is the login screen again. I switched on ubuntu on Xorg and (luckily) everything works. Once I tried to change the password and magically It worked for one day.... It's not a big deal, but I would increase my knowledge about  Ubuntu
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Probably a graphic card drivers compatibility with Wayland.

Check your drivers:

```
glxinfo | grep "Vendor"
glxinfo | grep "direct rendering"
```

I did had that issue with pre-installed amdgpu once.

Also i suggest using ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa For latest mesa updates

Comment: Thank you 

linux@charlie:~$ glxinfo | grep "Vendor"
    Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
linux@charlie:~$ glxinfo | grep "direct rendering"
direct rendering: Yes

Comment: unluckily  mesa didn't worked for me